# Delete end/trailing commas in some lines in a txt file

Tags: python, string

I have tried and searched in the site but i couldnt find a good solution suitable for my issue.
I have a large txt file. In the txt file randomly some lines are ending with `,`(commas). I want to get rid of the end commas.

**my sample file:**

```
TYPE,4.0,
ID,ZBC173,
ROW1,51.977,
ROW2,0,
ROW3,0,
ROW4,2,
81.00,-4.42,1.0
114.00,-1.67,1.0
ROW7,0,
ROW8,3.696,
ROW9,7,
113.9996969,-1.67,0.7
121.500409,0,0.7
127.9995187,0.066,0.9
129.4998186,0.285,0.9
134.4992436,1.779,1.0
145.9999685,2.144,1.0
153.2586833,3.696,1.0
```

my code:

```
import os
file=open(r'C:\Users\ZBC173.txt','r')
target=open(r'C:\Users\ZBC173_no_comma.csv','w')
states = [line.strip().split(':')[-1] for line in file.readlines()]
target.write('\n'.join(states))
target.close()
```

my output:

```
TYPE,4.0
ID,ZBC173
ROW1,51.977
ROW2,0
ROW3,0
ROW4,2
81.00,-4.42
114.00,-1.67
ROW7,0
ROW8,3.696
ROW9,7
113.9996969,-1.67
121.500409,0
127.9995187,0.066
129.4998186,0.285
134.4992436,1.779
145.9999685,2.144
153.2586833,3.696
```

in my output i miss some data. how can i avoid this? thanks for your support. i am a beginner for python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this context manager:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\ZBC173.txt','r') as file,open(r'C:\Users\ZBC173_no_comma.csv','w') as target:
    target.write(file.read().replace(',\n','\n'))
```

---

If you want to store all the text files in a folder into a different csv files:

```
from glob import glob

for f in glob("*.txt"):
    with open(f,'r') as file,open(f"C:\\Users\\Folder\\{f.replace('.txt','.csv')}",'w') as target:
        target.write(file.read().replace(',\n','\n'))
```

Comment: @ Ann Zen, Super. your code works good. How can i apply your code if i want to change all the files in a folder and write to another folder?

Comment: thank you for you answer. for example i have in folder1  `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`  and  `file3.txt` etc,  i need `file1.csv`, `file2.csv`  and  `file3.csv` etc, in folder2,  i am  sorry for the miscommunication from my side. i hope you understand me. Thank you again

Comment: @ Ann Zen, thank you. I will try the code and let you know. I am not near my PC.

Comment: i just tried with your code but got the follwoing error `with open(file,'r') as file,open(file.replace('.txt','.csv'),'w') as target:`  `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'replace'` can you check this?

Comment: It's a mixed up variable case. I fixed it now :)

Comment: Thank you it worked perfect. one last issue.Now  i want these csv files( target) in a different folder is this possible?

Comment: I added it to the post *put all the csv files in Folder*

Comment: i got ~ {f.replace('.txt','.csv')} ` this in my folder. i think something is missing in the code.

Comment: @ Ann Zen, i have got the syntax error `}"` doouble quotes here

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake i used python2. in python3 it worked perfect. i thank you once again for your kind response.

Comment: Sure, ofcourse  i have done it. Thank you and have a good day.

Comment: Hi Ann Zen, can u look into this issue [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/q/69253114/9975289}

Answer (score 1):

Use builtin [rstrip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) function:

```
file=open(r'C:\Users\ZBC173.txt','r')
target=open(r'C:\Users\ZBC173_no_comma.csv','w')
for line in file:
    target.write(line[:-1].rstrip(',') + "\n")

file.close()
target.close()
```

Comment: thank you for your response. i tried your code output remains same. nothing changed.

Comment: Oh, you are right. It is because every line ends with a `"\n"` character. So it shouldn't be included while stripping. I edited my answer, it should work now.